# starting out with ktor and getting random gradle issues, what could be wrong, where to start?

Tags: gradle, ktor

I'm getting started with KTOR and getting gradle errors with various sample projects...

I tried the *Ktor generator* and then the *KTOR documentation snippet project* and both are not building/syncing.
Should I be using IntelliJ Ultimate? (currently I have IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition))

The tutorial-server-get-started gives me: `Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':tutorial-server-get-started'.`
And the online generated project was giving me something about `Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '2.2.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

I tried to find fixes online, but seems like one error leads to another, so maybe I have to start with some specific instructions? Thank you.

Below are the contents of the generated gradle.kts

```
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "2.2.3"
    application
                id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")

    val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network-tls-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-websockets:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth-jwt:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
}
```

[image]

[image]

gradlew.properties

```
ktor_version=1.8.10
kotlin_version=2.2.3
logback_version=1.2.11
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Comment: How did you run a generated project? What plugins did you choose on start.ktor.io for a new project?

Comment: I chose a random set of plugins, but I get the error on the gradle sync, I modified the question with my generated gradle.kts

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 Community Edition. Can you try to invalidate IDEA's caches?

Comment: I invalidated caches but no difference. I added the screenshot of my gradle jvm, is it ok?

Comment: The problem is that the version for `kotlin("jvm") version "2.2.3"` is incorrect. It should be `1.8.10`. This is probably due to the randomly reproducible bug in Ktor's project generator.

Comment: Ok after changing the jvm to 1.8.10 it started syncing, but now every single dependency is complaining about wrong version.

Comment: Can you share the gradle.properties file?

Comment: added gradle.properties

Comment: Oh my god. Please swap the versions of the `ktor_version` and `kotlin_version` parameters in the `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: That was good, most of the dependencies were resolved, only unresolved ones are the auth* ones, also if I disable auth* dependencies , the io.ktor.application.* is not being resolved.

Comment: Can you please regenerate a project in start.ktor.io?

Comment: Fantastic, this time is a lot better, in fact everything works. There is one error about  `Property jwt.audience not found.` but after desabling the jwt auth block the server runs. Thank you